gRpc bidirectional streaming stuck when it's loads of messages
Got interesting problem with bidirectional streaming through grpc connection in .Net.
I have three servers, like client <-> client-server <-> server.
client write in request stream requests, client-server process it (sort of), and server makes another requests to third party services (which is kinda slow).
Problem occures when i write to request stream on client several dozens big requests (about 35-37 kb), server (through client-server) receives it, and starts process it.
Server relies on await foreach IAsyncEnumerable, so it reads first, process it, write response to response stream and then read next request.
But after processing first request, he can not write response to response stream, and consequently it can not read another request.
I believe it's because of GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE  parameter which is 65k by default. And if channel buffer is full of requests, there is literally no space for response, which is, basically, a deadlock.
The most obvious solution - read all from request channel, store this request in some array and then just foreach it. But, unfortunately, this project has a use case, when response data uses as a request for another service, and response is, basically, this data with some enrichments.
So with this case in mind, i can not use obvious solution, because in that case i would store all response in memory. And it can be hundreds of megabytes.
I tried to increase InitialHttp2StreamWindowSize in SocketHttpHandler which i use for GrpcChannel creation, to it maximum and it resolves the problem, but i realize it is a temporary solution.
Setting EnableMultipleHttp2Connections in the same SocketHttpHandler doesn't help at all.
I'm very keen to find out about more permanent solution, like splitting channel buffer between request and response or something.
I'm using Grpc.AspNetCore 2.63.0
Also i created MRE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13JFrQp8KeSNZ6D8TQJjpKl5rNbaBYB7s/view?usp=drive_link
I'd be extremly grateful for any ideas
